# split data frame index by separator and convert into columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4]})
df.index = ['A:100','B:103','C:105','D:108']
```

I'm trying to split the index at `:` and convert the output into columns `y` and `z`:

```
x   y   z
1   A   100
2   B   103
3   C   105
4   D   108
```

I thought this would work:

```
df[['y','z']] = df.index.str.split(':', expand=True)
```

but I get a `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Comment: `df[['y','z']] = df.index.str.split(':', expand=True).to_list()` also works.

Comment: @QuangHoang that's as good as any of the other answers, you should post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

use `to_series`

```
df[['y','z']] = df.index.to_series().str.split(':', expand=True)
```

df:

```
       x  y    z
A:100  1  A  100
B:103  2  B  103
C:105  3  C  105
D:108  4  D  108
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your code, assigning the result (a MultiIndex) back to the index and then using `reset_index` to convert to columns:

```
df.index = df.index.str.split(':', expand=True)
df = df.reset_index(names=['y', 'z'])
```

Output:

```
   y    z  x
0  A  100  1
1  B  103  2
2  C  105  3
3  D  108  4
```